# How do i merge columns of 5 dataframes into one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code :

```
stock_A = pd.DataFrame(data[:5])
stock_B = pd.DataFrame(data[5:11])
stock_C = pd.DataFrame(data[11:16])
stock_D = pd.DataFrame(data[16:21])
stock_E = pd.DataFrame(data[21:26])

Close_price=pd.DataFrame()
Close_price['Stock A'] = stock_A['Close Price']
Close_price['Stock B'] = stock_B['Close Price']
Close_price['Stock C'] = stock_C['Close Price']
Close_price['Stock D'] = stock_D['Close Price']
Close_price['Stock E'] = stock_E['Close Price']
```

and the output I'm getting is

```
            Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D  Stock E
Date                                                   
2017-05-16   955.00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2017-05-17   952.80      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2017-05-18   961.75      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2017-05-19   957.95      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2017-05-22   961.45      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

I don't understand why am I getting 'NaN' values for the rest of the columns.
how do I get the actual values ?

Comment: Columns assignment aligns indexes. The 5 dataframes have different indexes, therefore you only have data in the first column.

Comment: okay, how do i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use the **concat** function to achieve this. You should try:

close_price = pd.concat([stock_A, stock_B, stock_C, stock_D, stock_E], axis=1)

The "axis" is important as it determines whether data is stacked horizontally or vertically (0=horizontal and 1=vertical).

If the indexes have been repeated use the reset_index() function to reset the indexes.